# Mixing valve mineral buildup cleaning

Tags: plumbing, cleaning, mixing-valve

Is there a chemical way, preferably by soaking, to remove mineral buildup from mixing valve parts, which would make it unnecessary to do tedious brushing? Also, do you think it is possible that excessive buildup may cause gaskets to not seal anymore and leak?

Comment: Soak in vinegar or a decalcifier like CLR.

Comment: If you have a build up and some of it gets between the gasket and sealing surface, then leaking is possible.  Enough could cause gasket damage if force or enough time is used.  Brushing is probably still needed with vinegar or similar stuff, but elbow grease is greatly reduced to almost a wipe.